# IP address loads faster than domain name

Tags: ip, http, domain-name, speed

I just signed up for a cloud server in Singapore. I myself am in Indonesia. I've got the domain name setup and everything. When I ping my IP address versus ping my domain name, the results are about the same. But when I load each of them through my browser, the IP address is quite a bit faster than the domain name. Would this be because of the DNS server? My distance between computer and server? Or something else? I'm using Namecheap's DNS server at the moment.

Need some advice from server gurus. Thanks!

Comment: Name resolution takes time, where as ping by IP skips that. So, I would say yes. You should use your ISP's DNS server if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DNS resolution takes time. Use a tool like firebug or the chrome dev tools to see how long resolution is taking.

Comment: +1: If you type in the domain name, the users DNS will go through the process of looking up the IP address, a step which obviously doesn't occur with a plain IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked with chrome dev and the results vary. I have a couple Domain Names pointing to the same IP address. One of them took as long as 45 seconds (!!!), the other one within 3-4 seconds, but maybe that's because I had already loaded the first one in the same browser? Yikes, that's really3 long...

Comment: I think it's something else. If I try the two with the Network tab open, the network tab reports about 7-15us for DNS lookup (already cached). And the Network tab also reports about the same amount of time total for getting the resource (50ms vs 60ms). 

But there's a very obvious 1-2 second delay after hitting enter and seeing the image load for the domain name that is not there for the IP address. I wonder if Chrome is doing something shady like looking up the domain name in a blocklist or reporting it to google or something?

I just checked Firefox and it does not have the same delay.

Answer (score 0):

Namecheap's DNS records will eventually be cached all over the world so if the TTL is big enough it shouldn't really matter.  What I'm more concerned with is your selection in DNS servers; there are several DNS benchmarking tools out there that'll choose the right DNS servers for your computer, I know that Steve Gibson wrote one...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The TTL is set to 1800, Namecheap's default I believe. Is that long enough? Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by "my selection" in DNS servers. Do you mean me personally, on my local computer? I just let my ISP take care of it I suppose...

Comment: I used [Namebench](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/downloads/detail?name=namebench-1.3.1-Mac_OS_X.dmg) for OSX just now. It told me Google's, Fast Net's, and Power.Net's DNS are best for me. I'll try inputting those in my router.

Answer (score 0):

Try this DNS benchmarking tool, and see what is best for you in your location:

http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Comment: Thank you! I will try that, and also I just tried [Namebench](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/downloads/detail?name=namebench-1.3.1-Mac_OS_X.dmg). It gave me 3 fastest DNS. I'll try them on my router.